# Trying to understand WordPress theme php

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, themes

I'm confused, more than normal, I'm messing around in a theme, trying to understand (something)..

this is from header.php

```
<?php thinkup_bodystyle(); ?>
```

I think it's calling for the following function, that I only found in another PHP file:
(00.themesetup.php)

```
do_action('thinkup_bodystyle');
```

but that's it, nowhere else is the word bodystyle mentioned, not in any files..
so, what is this?
what is it supposed to do for action?

.. feeling confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's calling a function, both times, called thinkup_bodystyle(). We can't read you code, so either there IS a function called thinkup_bodystyle() somewhere, or the code you've shown isn't getting activated somehow, or there is some kind of error catching mechanism going on. In anycase you'd imagine this function spits out some kind of CSS or something.

Comment: Could this call activate any php that the theme (or wordpress) has included  previously, or just the includes  that are in the calling php page?

It could also be that the call function is implanted but the code is only available  on pro..

Comment: [That's a separate question, probably better to just ask seperately]. Absolutely. WordPress functions generally live in the global name space. It was almost certainly declared somewhere else in your theme.